# Route global shortcuts to pages opened in Firefox

Tags: firefox, shortcuts

I like listening to music online on sites like stereomood.com. There is a major problem, however. I can not control the player with my keyboard. And even with a mouse - when I want to play/pause I must activate firefox window, select the tab where music plays and hit play/pause button manually - this is a pain, especially when you play a fullscreen game that can not minimize itself. Thus said, global keyboard shortcuts would be a perfect solution. I understand that different online media players have different controls and each site must be configured individually (like, select button with id 'play' and press it), but I believe that can be done in principle.

I also guess that such tricks are impossible without some third-party native app which captures shortcuts and routes them to Firefox window.

So, any solutions? Maybe some AutoHotkey hacks or similar.

Answer (score 1):

A little while ago, I found myself wishing I had some keyboard shortcuts for Grooveshark, so I did some research, and I found [this nifty firefox addon](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension). It's called keyconfig, and it allows you to make your own shortcuts with a little coding knowledge.

From what I can tell, no one has already made a shortcut for playing/stopping that specific media player, so you'll have to do a little coding to get it to work, but I was able to find a working code for Grooveshark, so it shouldn't be that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Media Keys add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/media-keys/) does what I want.

Github page [here](https://github.com/carlin-q-scott/browser-media-keys).